# How to install a clean 32 bit WineHQ into a 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: wine, 32-bit

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS and I still use three 32 bit days Windows Software through WineHQ 3.0.4.

Even the fact that 64 bit WineHQ can run those programs almost fine... There is some issues (audio noise, stuttering, etc).

I guess, only guess, it is due because WineHQ is always installed to work as 64 bit mode Windows, but those apps were made in the age of 32 bit, so...

I've been looking for some easy instructions to install, from the scratch, a clean 32 bit mode WineHQ, but... The "instructions" are not enough clear to me.

Can somebody teach me how to get that 32 bit clean installation, please?

Answer (score 0):

Wine will start an 64-bit environment by default. You can change this behavior using the `WINEARCH` environment variable. Rename your `~/.wine` directory and create a new Wine environment by running `$ WINEARCH=win32 winecfg`. This will get you a 32-bit Wine environment. Not setting `WINEARCH` will get you a 64-bit one.
You can combine this with `WINEPREFIX` to make a separate win32 and win64 environment:

> $ WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/win32 winecfg
>   $ WINEPREFIX=~/win64 winecfg

Additional info you can find, for example, here: [Wine ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wine)

Comment: I will test your idea. But.. I wonder... Why the user has to do this??? Shouldn't Wine to detect which software needs 32 bit and which needs 64 bits automatically, and perform the mode "switch" in a silent ,invisible way?